# Convert DBF to CSV in MS Access

Tags: vba, csv, ms-access, dbf

In MS Access, is there a way using VBA to export an arbitrary DBF file to CSV format without needing to manually export it first / create a specification file? I just want to make a function that will work for any DBF. Is there a function that does this already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an arbitrary file, but you can use

```vb
DoCmd.TransferDatabase acLink, ...
' and
DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, ...
```

to first link a specific dBase file, then export it to a text file. Using neither an import/link specification nor an export specification, the commands will use the default settings of Access.

Comment: I am trying to export to .csv though, not .txt

Comment: A csv file is a text file.